# Why navigation drawer isn't full height

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

This ![Navigation Drawer isn't full height] https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzQh4.png "How can I do it?".

I'm using recyclerview not using listview.

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Navigation Drawer Fragment**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   tools:context="com.dumposk129.create.stories.materialdesign.v1.NavigationDrawerFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_wallpaper" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/containerDrawerImage" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlayFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/containerDrawerImage">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overlayImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see the code for fragment_navigation_drawer.xml?

Comment: I was added fragment_navigation_drawer.xml .

Comment: try change those `wrap_content` in `layout_height` to match parent

Comment: Where I change layout height?

Comment: Doesn't work. Do you have another way?